# Drawing a Entity-Relationship Diagram with No Relationships

Tags: database-design, erd

As a school project I have made a small database with two tables, `users` and `rooms`.

- `users` has two columns: `username` and `password`
- `rooms` has `room_name`, `room no`, `size`

Can an entity-relationship diagram (ERD) be made for this? Since there isn't a relationship I'm not sure how.

At the application program tier, the project just uses PHP to let the users login and get the details of the room.

Comment: I recommend you add a table called `bookings`, where a user can book a room. That would give you a connection between your users and rooms and allow you to play with more cool stuff in your DB model (joins, many to many relationships, linking tables etc..) :-)

Comment: When creating a model (in form of an ERD), one of the aims is: to find "strong" relationships eg we don't just draw lines that connect an entity to all the other entities.  It seems that - in your example - the relationship between ROOM and USER is "weak".  Maybe it is a many-to-many relationship (each user can use zero/one or more rooms, each room can be used by zero/one or more users).  If this is the case, then a BOOKING entity could be used to connect the 2 entities (as @Oreo suggested).  BOOKING would have "stronger" relationships (to USER and ROOM).